# How to prevent flickering when showing a view controller in another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I want to show a view only one time when a main view controller is shown for the first time.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!self.isMainViewShowedBefore)
    {
        self. self.isMainViewShowedBefore = YES;

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: temporaryViewController];

        [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:NO completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

It works but the main screen appears for a short time before the temporary view controller is shown.

I tried to add above code in viewWillAppear but I got below error

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to begin a
>   modal transition from  to
>    while a transition is already in
>   progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current
>   transition has completed'

How can I hide the main controller before the temporary view controller is shown?

Answer (score 1):

Add `temporaryViewController.view` as a subview of `self.view` (your main view controller)

```
[self.view addSubview:temporaryViewController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the error in viewWillAppear because you can't do two animations together in iOS, it might get your app crashed but most of the time iOS is nice to us, it just gives us a warning.

Now my main concern, why would you add this main view controller if you don't want to use it at all? and this is not flickering, this is a normal behaviour, if you want the UINavigationController to appear, simply sow it instead of this "main view controller".

If you have more hidden logic that would prevent you from doing what I said, please tell me.

Comment: This is a photo application and I want to crop the photo when it loaded first time.

Comment: and the crop view controller is a third party controller and I don't want to change it